# Making changes to a frontend repo, linked to a docker repo (0x Launch Kit)

Tags: docker, github, frontend, blockchain, repo

I know this might seem like an obvious question and a bit general, but I just started playing around with the Launch Kit by 0x (https://github.com/0xProject/0x-launch-kit) and have successfully deployed the example app, but would now like to proceed and customize the frontend.

I see that the repository I linked above, used to build the app, is actually a docker repo for both the frontend and API repos:
https://github.com/0xProject/0x-launch-kit-frontend
https://github.com/0xProject/0x-api

Do I need to fork all three repos for this to work (docker, frontend and api) to my own GitHub account and make changes to the frontend repo? If so, do I need to change anything in the cloned docker repo for the app to use my new frontend code when building?

Would appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Customising the frontend will require you to find and edit the correct files inside the node modules. Which is not recommended unless you know what you're doing. Note that 'yarn' or 'npm install' with undo all your changes you make to any node modules.
One way to go about it is to use the "patch-package" to patch the node modules after editing it. For example, "npx patch-package name-of-package". This is a tedious method.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to fork the uikit and create a custom kit from it on the npmjs website. Then call it into to you project.

Catgirl is a good example of this in play.

[image: Catgirl dependencies forked form pancakeswap]